Json serializing from stream to a sequence
I'm using FSharpLu to serialize and deserialize JSON.
The JSON file I'm trying to deserialize has just 1 huge array.
I have this function to deserialize from a stream
let read<'T> (path: string) : 'T =
    use stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(path)
    Compact.deserializeStream stream

let x = read<MyType seq> pathToFile

Is the file read and deserialized when the read function is called or is it only done when I try to access some elements of x (Because it is a sequence and it is lazy) ?
I stumbled upon this question when I tried to verify that the serializer is working fine.
I created two copies of the same data in two paths
let x = read<MyType seq> path1
let y = read<MyType seq> path2
printfn "%A" (x=y)

and to my surprise, it printed false.
But when I use MyType list instead of MyType seq it prints true.
So what exactly is happening when I use a seq?

When you compare two different sequences, you are not really comparing their content, you are comparing their "enumerator" or, in your case, their stream reader due to lazy evaluation. Since the two stream readers are different, the result is indeed false.
The comparison of sequences is "vicious" when you expect them to be compared by content. For more information about comparing seq, you could refer to this other question.

Thanks for the answer, I did not know that's how comparison works for sequences. If I'm comparing their stream readers, does that mean the reading and serialization is only done when I "ask" for a value from the sequence ?

@JansenVanBeek In principle, yes, although the lib you are using may use other internal mechanisms that I don't know about. The calculation of the contents of a sequence is delayed until you explicitly request one or more elements of that sequence. That's why it's called lazy evaluation.
